# Oozie sharelib does not exists

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am setting up oozie for first time. After all the setup is done, when I ran example workflows, they failed. And `-errorlog` shows following message

```
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: 
File /user/userName/share/lib does not exist
```

I did run the below command to create sharelib while doing setup and I can see the sharelib with all the jars in hdfs webconsole-

```
./oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000
```

but when I verify the available sharelib using

```
oozie admin -shareliblist
```

it shows only `[Availble Sharelib]` message with no libs actually listed.

Any idea, what can be the issue?

[image: HDFS webconsole screen shot of share lib]

Comment: Try running `./oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000 -locallib  /path/to/sharelib`

Comment: I removed existing share folder in HDFS ,stopped oozie server and tried  `$OOZIE_HOME/bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000 -locallib /usr/local/Cellar/oozie/oozie-sharelib-4.3.0.tar.gz` and restarted ozzie again. Unfortunately, there is no change in job output. it still failed

Comment: What does `hdfs dfs -ls /user/username/share/` return?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   - username supergroup          0 2017-02-26 13:44 /user/username/share/lib

Comment: Try adding this propety to `oozie-site.xml`, `<name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
        <value>/user/username/share/lib</value>`

Comment: I added it in oozie-site.xml and restarted but didnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136703/discussion-between-franklinsijo-and-pushkr).